# How to obtain userrole of Username passed via querystring parameter

Tags: asp.net

I need to identify user role of the username passed through querystring. I am using SQL database and working in aspnet. Can someone suggest how it can achieved?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? Are you using MS/My SQL ? Database or What?

Comment: just updated my original question with the info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE [UserId] = 'REQUESTED_USERNAME' && [Password] = 'REQUESTED_PASSWORD'";

    string strCon = System.Web
                          .Configuration
                          .WebConfigurationManager
                          .ConnectionStrings["SocialSiteConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strCon);
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader nwReader = comm.ExecuteReader();
    while (nwReader.Read())
    {
        int UuserRole = (int)nwReader["UserROLE"];
    //do some stuffs

    }
    nwReader.Close();
    conn.Close();
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. How can I use this to hide a Panel depending on the role?

Comment: Thats true simple. Use if else statement 
`<%
if(condition)
{%>

html code

<% } 
else 
{
%>
html code
<% } %>`